# Magento 2 direct SQL query for insert not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sql, query

I was trying to insert values into **mlx_cot_custom_option_type_value** because module files are encrypted. I want to add something after product save

I am using **catalog_product_save_after** event

Here is what I have tried.

```
    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    } 
    
    $this->connection = $this->_resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $option_id = 186;
    $valueTable = 'mlx_cot_custom_option_type_value';
    $table = $this->_resource->getTableName($valueTable); 
    
    echo $sql = "Insert Into " . $table . " (option_type_id, option_id, sku, sort_order,weight) Values ('','".$option_id."','".$value['sku']."','1','')";
    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->connection->lastInsertId());
    die;
```

Output is

```
Insert Into mlx_cot_custom_option_type_value (option_type_id, option_id, sku, sort_order,weight) Values ('','186','Custom-Create-Any-Song-in-a-Music-Box-New','1','')

2047
```

$this->connection->lastInsertId() give new increment id every time but I can not see any new entry into database

When I run above query using phpmyadmin it will create new entry

Comment: Same issue with me when try to insert order id in custom table on after place order event but not working

Comment: I was trying to do this using event but when i try to do this with plugin it is working

Comment: Please share your code that is working

Comment: Try to run the above output - Insert query directly into database so that we can check if sql is working fine. And can you show me your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are trying to save an attribute to product through observer "catalog_product_save_after", then this can be help:
https://webkul.com/blog/mass-update-products-attribute-magento-2/